# How to adjust window placement in Unity, Ubuntu 14.04 based on overlapping top bar

Tags: unity, window

[image: Window Issue]

Ever since I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 from 13.10, I will have windows that open with the top bar of the window obscured by the top bar of the screen. I can move the window once it is open,  and then accessbut it is a minor inconvenience to do so.

I saw some historic threads that mentioned a Compiz manager to adjust this, but I didn't know if it was still the preferred way or if it was obsoleted.

I think the issue is that the window that opens is too large to be fully displayed in the screen, and before the OS preferred to put the window bar just under the top bar. I was missing more on the bottom, but I could easily access the bar to close the window. Now it seems to split the difference and put the window centered with a bit obscured at the top and the bottom. I am missing the bar at the top, and I don't see the bottom of the window either.

Thanks!

Edit: Posted screenshot of issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best workaround I have come up with is:

- Install `compizconfig-settings-manager` from the software center
- Run compizconfig-settings-manager
- Go to place windows
- Go to fix windows placement tab
- Create new (windows with fixed positions)
- Window postion: class= "the program that is loading in the wrong position"
- X=65
- Y=55

Then close

Repeat as needed for all program causing problems and adjust `X` & `Y` based on you launcher and panel scaling.
some time you have to restart for the setting to take effect.

hope this helps
cheers!
Whitaar

Comment: This worked for me. I ended up having Y at 308, which lined it up perfectly with the top bar. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue too. I avoided it simply using the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Click</kbd> to move the window.

Comment: As the author of the question noted, that he can move the window once it is open, I'd say, he is already aware of this feature but is still looking for a way to prevent this from even happening.

Comment: That is correct. Moving the window after it opens is possible. @Mecio, are you using Ubuntu 14.04 as well? If so, what is your graphics adapter? My laptop uses an Intel Ivybridge Mobile adapter. If you have a similar adapter, it could be something specific to it. If not, it could be a generic setting in Ubuntu somewhere.