# Firefox and Google Chrome browser pop-ups not always showing window title bar in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: titlebar

Firefox and Google Chrome browser pop-ups 80% of the time not showing window title bar in Ubuntu 14.04. If you increase the window size the title bar appears. Also the indicator in the launcher icon does not show the window as open until you click on the launcher icon.

I have reproduce this on Nvidia and Intel graphics hardware using both open and close source drivers. I have not tried it on ati graphics yet

I believe that it is Compiz not sizing the windows correctly causing the problem.

does anyone know a fix to this? It gets really annoying with website with lots of pop-ups.

Answer (score 0):

Is this similar to my question I asked at [How to adjust window placement in Unity, Ubuntu 14.04 based on overlapping top bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452995/how-to-adjust-window-placement-in-unity-ubuntu-14-04-based-on-overlapping-top-b/454312?noredirect=1#454312) ?

I have been unable to get an answer as of yet. So far, Firefox is the worst offender, with RDP windows through rdesktop being the second worst.

Comment: the best workaround I have come up with is:
- install compizconfig-settings-manager from the software center
- run compizconfig-settings-manager
- go to place windows
- go to fix windows placement tab
- create new (windows with fixed positions)
- window postion: class= "the program that is loading in the wrong position"
- X=65
- Y=55
then close
 repeat as needed for all program causing problems and adjust X & Y based on you launcher and panel scaling.
some time you have to restart for the setting to take effect.

hope this helps
cheers!
Whitaar