# All Firefox pop-ups dont have close or minimise button

Tags: firefox

All firefox click pop-ups dont have close button. I have to click the launcher icon to show both the windows, only from there i can close it.

Is there any fix. I have disable pop-ups on default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this related to the question I asked at [How to adjust window placement in Unity, Ubuntu 14.04 based on overlapping top bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452995/how-to-adjust-window-placement-in-unity-ubuntu-14-04-based-on-overlapping-top-b/454312?noredirect=1#454312) ?

I have not gotten an answer yet. If this is a common problem (which it seems to be) eventually there will be an answer. Until then, the only workaround is to hold 
<kbd>Left Alt</kbd> and then click and drag the window down. This will let you access the bar.

Comment: actually in my it is nor because of unity launcher, the top bar of pop-up is not at all visible. however if use ALT and drag it, the control appears. i think even in your case its not because of unity launcher, try to autohide the launcher and see

Comment: I added the launcher autohide and it the window was still missing its top bar. It just opened farther to the left.

Comment: The question I posted in this answer has finally got an answer! See if it works for you: http://askubuntu.com/a/458082/272113