# How to move guake terminal window

Tags: 14.04, guake

When I open guake terminal, it shows up in the top half of my monitor by default. I wanted it to appear in the bottom half. How do I do this?

Comment: Does this help - http://askubuntu.com/a/458082/119531 ?

Comment: No not really. @Raphael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Guake preferences (through it's application starter, the context menu of the Guake window, or the `guake-prefs` program) in the *General* tab and enable set the check box labelled “Bottom align window instead of top align” (see highlighted text below) according to you liking.

[image: General Guake preferences]

Answer (score 1):

With new Guake versions (>= 0.8.5), moving the window is pretty easy though. You just have to go to `preferences --> General --> Placement` and check the `Bottom align window instead of top align` checkbox.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned it in the end. Anyways, I changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Run `guake-prefs` from the terminal.